# Scrapy ::attr(href) returns #

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm new timer with scrapy 1.4 and python ...

```
response.css("a#pagination-next::attr(href)").extract()
```

returns only `['#']`

original link is :

```
<a class="link_pagination next" id="pagination-next" title="Next Page" href="/directory/find?who=butcher&amp;where=Kentucky%20%2833%29&amp;idOu=D033&amp;page=2&amp;contexte=g78qcp7j9uJRt6Zef4pNMwxISMRndNFsTX8Pg%2Byl0iE%3D&amp;proximity=0&amp;" data-pjstats="{&quot;idTag&quot;:&quot;PAGE-NEXT&quot;,&quot;pjscript&quot;:&quot;xt_click({},'C','{%xtn2}','LR::pagination::page_next','N');&quot;}">            <span class="value">Next</span>
        <span class="icon icon-lt-arrow-right"></span>
    </a>
```

Any suggestion ?

Thks in advance four your help
:)

p

Comment: maybe site have `#` as url and it uses JavaScript to replace it with correct url. Scrapy can't run JavaScript so it gives you `#`. You may have to use `Selenium` which let you control web browser which will load this page and run javascript.

Comment: it works as expected for me, could you please share the url? are you sure the `a` do contains the `href`, please try checking the `response.body` received by scrapy

Comment: @wilfredo

for example : https://www.pagesjaunes.fr/annuaire/chercherlespros?quoiqui=fleuriste&ou=Gironde%20%2833%29&idOu=D033&page=1&contexte=g78qcp7j9uJRt6Zef4pNMwxISMRndNFsTX8Pg%2Byl0iE%3D&proximite=0&quoiQuiInterprete=fleuriste


link is at the bottom ...

Comment: @furas

I understand your suggestion ... not sure of it.

I can extract all the other attribute (id, title, data-pjstats) ... but not href.
And, for me, if Scrapy display it, it knows it.

thks for your help

Comment: the href I'm looking to extract (as displayed in scrapy shell mode) is :

/annuaire/chercherlespros?quoiqui=fleuriste&ou=Gironde%20%2833%29&idOu=D033&page=2&contexte=g78qcp7j9uJRt6Zef4pNMwxISMRndNFsTX8Pg%2Byl0iE%3D&proximite=0&quoiQuiInterprete=fleuriste

Comment: it's late here ...

I'll see your advices tomorrow morning
:)

Comment: If Scrapy display then it should be available. But I check source code and I see `id="pagination-next" title="Page suivante" href="#"`

Comment: The url is base64 encoded, please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

The url is generated using javascript, but luckily the url is still there, try this:

```
import base64
import json

...
url_meta = response.css('#pagination-next::attr(data-pjlb)').extract_first()
url_in_base64 = json.loads(url_meta)['url']
next_page_url = response.urljoin(base64.b64decode(url_in_base64).decode('utf-8'))
# then you can yield a Request(next_page_url)
```

Comment: Great !
Just have to spend sometimes on the docs to learn the process
:)

Comment: Please, if the answer helped you, feel free to mark this question as answered.